# Why wont my closure function work?

Tags: javascript, closures

The function below adds arguments within 1 paranthesis fine. For example, it computes `addTogether(2,3) = 5` and `addTogether(2,"3") = undefined`.

However, it fails to compute `addTogether(2)(3) = 5`, instead giving me the error that *"addTogether(...) is not a function"*. The closure function (`return function(x)`) is supposed to take into the second argument in `addTogether(2)(3)`, and I'm lost on why it dos not work.

```js
function addTogether() {

  if (typeof arguments[0] !== "number" || typeof arguments[1] !== "number") {
    return undefined;
  } //not harmful but not necessary
  var sum = 0;
  var num = arguments[0];

  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    //if only 1 argument in the original function...
    if (typeof arguments[0] !== "number") {
      return undefined;
      //returns undefined if arguments[0] isnt a number
    }

    return function(x) {
      if (typeof arguments[0] !== "number") {
        return undefined;
        //in the closure/2nd function, if first argument isnt a number then no sum will be provided
      } else {
        sum = num + x; //x = second given argument
        return sum;
      }
    };

  }

  if (typeof arguments[0] === "number" && typeof arguments[1] === "number") {

    for (var x = 0; x < arguments.length; x++) {
      if (typeof arguments[x] === "number") {
        sum += arguments[x];
        //add the argument[0] and [1] if both are number types, not string or array types or any other types
      } else {
        sum = undefined;
      }
    }

    return sum;

  }
  // the above "if" statement is rsponsible for achieving addTogether(2,3) = 5;

}

console.log(addTogether(2)(3));
```

Comment: `if (typeof arguments[0] !== "number" || typeof arguments[1] !== "number")` already causes `addTogether(2)` to return `undefined`.

Comment: ^ If you only pass a single argument, `typeof arguments[1] !== "number"` is `true` (because `typeof arguments[1]` will return `"undefined"`).

Comment: The comment "Not harmful but not necessary" is wrong. It's not necessary, and it's harmful.

Comment: @Xufox Turn that into an answer.

Comment: FWIW, you could have easily find out why the function doesn't return a function if you used your browser's developer tools and set a breakpoint at the beginning of function. Take the time to learn how to debug JavaScript. It's invaluable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your function to work like `addTogether(2)(3)`, this means that your 
`addTogether` must take an parameter and return a function. `addTogether(2)` this call will return a new function, and then call the returned function with the second parameter.

In your case when you compare

```
if (typeof arguments[0] !== "number" || typeof arguments[1] !== "number")
```

and call the function with one argument, the second `typeof arguments[1] !== "number"` returns you `true`, because the second parameter is `undefined`, so it is not a number and your function returns `undefined`.

And in your code you can remove some conditions also. Because the above condition will already check them.

```js
function addTogether() {

  if (typeof arguments[0] !== "number") { 
    return undefined;
  } 
  var sum = 0;
  var num = arguments[0];

  if (arguments.length === 1) {  

    return function(x) {
      if (typeof arguments[0] !== "number") {
        return undefined;
        
      } else {
        sum = num + x; 
        return sum;
      }
    };

  }

  if (typeof arguments[0] === "number" && typeof arguments[1] === "number") {

    for (var x = 0; x < arguments.length; x++) {
      if (typeof arguments[x] === "number") {
        sum += arguments[x];
        
      } else {
        sum = undefined;
      }
    }

    return sum;

  }
  
}

console.log(addTogether(2)(3));
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but doesnt the (return function(x)) return that new function? Im confused how to fix this

Comment: @Pythonnoob Edited

Answer (score 1):

`if (typeof arguments[0] !== "number" || typeof arguments[1] !== "number")` already causes `addTogether(2)` to return `undefined`.

Placing that `if` statement at the end of the function or turning that `||` into an `&&` fixes it.